# Need Google Spreadsheet Formula to get all same-postal code cities on a single row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Looking **to get all same-postal code cities on a single row**

On a sheet I have thousands of postal codes from Australia and the cities that are tied to those postal codes.

There are two main columns:

1. The Postal Codes
2. The cities that are part of those postal codes.

The postal codes repeat themselves, while the each of the cities are obviously unique. For example, postcode 2408 has 3 cities tied to it.

My problem is I can't come up with a formula to get the cities (that are tied to a unique postcode) names all into one cell. So the post code is on one column and the names of the cities are on another.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Check the answer by @player0 on StackExchange: [List unique values in 1 column and concatenate corresponding values in other column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58402992/1330560). You don't say whether your post codes are entered as text or numbers; if they are numbers then you can easily convert them to text using `TEXT()`. This might be a quick-and-dirty solution until someone brighter than me can re-work the regexreplace component of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({UNIQUE(A3:A),TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(IF(A3:A=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A3:A)),B3:B&",",),,9^99)&"|"),", |",""))},"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 is not null order by Col1 label Col1 'Post Code',Col2 'City/Suburb' "))`

---

**Sample data**

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

## Approach Using BYROW

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A), LAMBDA(r,
   TOROW({r; FILTER(B:B, A:A=r)})))
```

- BYROW passes each row from an array of UNIQUE **postal codes** one-by-one into a LAMBDA function that stores the current row in the variable `r`.
- The LAMBDA's formula returns a single row array for `r` by:

  1. Creating a single column array where:

     - The first row is `r`
     - The remaining rows are crrated by FILTER which returns the **city names** where the **postal code** is `r`
  2. TOROW is then used to transpose the column to a row.

## Variable Name Arbitrary

The choice of `r` as the LAMBDA's  variable name is completely arbitrary, and was chosen simply because the stored value is a *row* and `r` is short. The name can be customized as you prefer.

For example:

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A), LAMBDA(aUniquePostalCode,
   TOROW({aUniquePostalCode; FILTER(B:B, A:A=aUniquePostalCode)})))
```